# Reading input from a file doesn't work for filenames containing spaces

Tags: batch-file

I have a case where I have to move over 15,000 files. There are many duplicates, so I parsed them by MD5 and now I have a list of file names in an input file (files.txt).
I want to read from it, then copy the listed files to a new directory.
I pulled an old batch that someone had written as a two-part simple script and modified it.

It works for files without spaces. How can I get this to cover all file names?
Also, can't I put all of this into one file?

Cstart.bat:

```
for /f %%x in (files.txt) do call copyfiles.bat
```

copyfiles.bat:

```
set filename=%1
copy "C:\temp\%filename%" "C:\temp\pruned files\"
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need to somehow pass quotes around the call to copyfiles.bat otherwise spaces separate the filename into multiple args. How you do that in a batch file, I haven't a clue without going and reading lots of docs (I'm not even sure how your passing the filename to copyfiles.bat at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't even pass the `filename` to `copyfiles.bat`, so it's not working with or without spaces. (If you need to confirm that, add `echo %1 %filename & pause` before the `copy` line in `copyfiles.bat` and run `cstart.bat`.)

With that being said, you can do it all in one file easily:

```
for /f %%x "tokens=1 delims=*" in (files.txt) do copy "C:\Temp\%%x" "C:\Temp\pruned files\%%x"
```

To make sure it works, just replace the `copy` in the line above with `echo` and run it from a command prompt.

I tested this with a text file named `test.txt` that contained the following:

```
One.txt
Two.txt
Three.txt
And Four.txt
```

with a batch file named `testcopy.bat` containing this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=*" %%x in (test.txt) do echo "C:\Temp\%%x" "C:\Temp\test this\%%x"
```

The above test showed this output:

```
e:\TempFiles>testcopy
"C:\Temp\One.txt" "C:\Temp\test this\One.txt"
"C:\Temp\Two.txt" "C:\Temp\test this\Two.txt"
"C:\Temp\Three.txt" "C:\Temp\test this\Three.txt"
"C:\Temp\And Four.txt" "C:\Temp\test this\And Four.txt"
```

Comment: Ken, Appreciate the response. 
This works until I get to a file with a space in the name. Then I get the same problem -- File cannot be found. (filename is "Copy of cleanXP.bat" in this case).

Comment: @AndyG: See my edited batch command, sample input, test .bat file, and sample output from those tests. :-)

Comment: @ Ken White: This is so simple, I'm embarrassed. Works like a charm once I got the fat-finger and token statement right.
Thank you for simplifying it to my level...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%x in ("my file list.txt") do copy "C:\temp\%%~x" "C:\temp\pruned files"
```